# Instantiating list of an object

Tags: c#, list, class, constructor

I'm sure this question has been answered before, but I'm honestly not sure how to find the answer, and my searching hasn't yielded any results; feel free to answer this question by closing the topic and pointing me to the correct question / answer.

Let's say I have a class representing a Member of my organization. The class has a constructor to instantiate the Member object, taking as a parameter the Member ID, and executing a database call to return the row representing the Member, along with whatever properties of the Member I'm interested in using.

What is the correct protocol for obtaining a list of members?

My database query is simple - I have a stored procedure which will return me the list of members that I'm interested in obtaining. But how do I represent that on the application level?

Right now, I have a constructor for the Member object that takes as an input a DataRow, and assigns all the relevant properties of the Member object. I'm then doing the following:

```
public static List<member> getList()
{
    DataTable dt = GetMemberList();
    List<member> memberList = new List<member>()
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) memberList.Add(new member(dr));
    return memberList;
}
```

Comment: This all depends on what you mean by "correct".

Comment: What is GetMemberList() returning? This could possibly be done in a few lines of code using linq.

Comment: GetMemberList is returning a DataTable object, with each row in the DataTable representing a row in my Member table in my database.

Comment: Please indicate in your code snippet which line you are having trouble with.

Comment: Can you share the GetMemberList method?

Comment: I mean, there is no method really - all i'm doing is calling my database to return a DataTable ... I'm not really sure what you're asking for. Do you want me to post the code that I'm using to call the database (using the ADO object)?

Comment: You can always ask this type of "best practice" question in the c# chat room here, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really nothing wrong with what you are doing currently.

```
        DataTable dt = GetMemberList();
        List<Member> memberList = new List<Member>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            memberList.Add(new Member(dr));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetMemberList` is  doing the work here, `getList` is merely an abstraction. What you are talking about though is a separation of concerns. Usually this is accomplished in a project with a database by separating out into layers, often referred to as an n-tier structure.

Pertaining to what you are asking about, this structure would contain a Data Access Layer (DAL) which handles the database interactions; a Service Layer which has the ability to manipulate the input and output of the DAL, and then return that data to a caller; and a Business Logic Layer, which would determine which service calls to make and how to compose the returned data.

How you implement that structure greatly depends on several factors:

- size of your project (is this for a small business or for everyone)
- size of your team (is it just you or are there many developers involved)
- testing (is there any testing, and how large is its coverage)
- timeline available (does it need to be done this week)
- sensitivity of data (are you dealing with financial data)
- personal preference (tabs or spaces or code cowboy)

Best practice would dictate different things depending on how those factors line up. If it is just you, then it is a lot more open to interpretation. If it is a team, then they probably already have guidelines for this type of thing.

I would suggest at the very least using a data access layer and a service layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your Member (I recommend using a capital M for your class) class looks like, but you can have your class constructor take the DataRow as a parameter and populate your properties like this: (I'm assuming property names and database column names here).

```
public class Member
{
    public Member(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        MemberID = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["MemberID"]);
        MemberName = Convert.ToString(dataRow["MemberName"]);
    }

    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
}
```

Not the best solution, but this should work with the code you have provided.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm currently doing - but I'm more interested in knowing how / where I should be putting the code to actually get that DataTable which I am iterating through to create each Member object

Comment: After reading your comment, I can make a suggestion of how I would do this. I put all of my database calls in static classes which return an object list (in your case the method would return `List<Member>`. So instead of returning the `DataTable`, use it in the method call to create your `Member` objects and put them in the list to be returned. Hopefully that helps.